# Оптимизация Python

Tags: python

Что поправить в коде, 
чтобы он проходил по времени за 2 секунды:

```py
N = 5
elements = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2] # Список с элементами
request = [1, 2, 3] # Список с запросами
def search(elements, request):
    array = elements[::-1]
    for element in request:
        try : temp = elements.index(element)   
        except ValueError: print('-1 -1')
        if element in elements:
            print(temp+1, N - array.index(element))

search(elements, request)
```

1 < N < 100000 Необходимо для каждого запроса, найти номер первого и последнего вхождения в список elements, если элемент не найден, то вывести '-1 -1'

Comment: Судя по условию задачи, здесь работа для find/rfind

Comment: А список не сортированный ли?

Comment: @MBo, список упорядоченный в порядке неубывания

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Раз список упорядочен, то гораздо быстрее будет использовать бинарный поиск - он сработает за логарифмическое время.

Подойдут `bisect_left` и `bisect_right` из модуля [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html)

```
import bisect
N = 5
elements = [1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5] # Список с элементами
request = [0, 1, 2, 3, 6] # Список с запросами
def search(elements, request):
    for element in request:
        l = bisect.bisect_left(elements, element)
        r = bisect.bisect_right(elements, element)
        if r == l or l >= len(elements) or r <= 0:
            print(element, -1, -1)
        else:
            print(element, l, r - 1)

search(elements, request)

0 -1 -1
1 0 1
2 -1 -1
3 2 4
6 -1 -1
```

P.S. Если запросов не больше, чем элементов, то выгоднее отсортировать запросы, а затем просто пройти по списку элементов по порядку - сортированные запросы гарантируют, что назад возвращаться не придется, и второй этап будет линейным.

Comment: валит все тот же третий тест. Закрадывается подозрение, что ошибка на стороне серва, а не у меня. Пойду спрошу у препода

Answer (score 1):

Если числа исключительно однозначные натуральные (0-9), то можно попробовать сделать так:

```
elements = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2] # Список с элементами
request = [1, 2, 3] # Список с запросами

mystr=''.join([str(x) for x in elements])
for i in request:        
    print(f"request: {i} -> first entry: {mystr.find(str(i))}, last entry: {mystr.rfind(str(i))}")
```

получим:

```
request: 1 -> first entry: 0, last entry: 1
request: 2 -> first entry: 2, last entry: 4
request: 3 -> first entry: -1, last entry: -1
```

​
**UPDATE**

Если же в исходном списке вообще сборная солянка, то можно сделать так:

```
elements = [1, 1, 2, 20.5, 2, 'boo', 5] # Список с элементами
request = [1, 2, 20.5, 3, 'boo', 6] # Список с запросами

res = [print(x,':',elements.index(x), len(elements) - 1- elements[::-1].index(x)) if x in elements else print(x,':', -1, -1) for x in request]
```

получим:

```
1 : 0 1
2 : 2 4
20.5 : 3 3
3 : -1 -1
boo : 5 5
6 : -1 -1
```

Comment: Числа не только натуральные :(

Comment: @link_brt обновил ответ. теперь осталось протестировать на скорость.

Comment: в исходном списке находятся числа, упорядоченные в порядке неубывания. Сейчас проверим на скорость

Comment: валит все на том же тесте

Comment: @link_brt Раз массив упорядоченный, то, скорей всего, нужно будет использовать, бинарный поиск или что-то в этом роде.

Comment: @Joker, попытался сделать двоичный поиск, в итоге с первым вхождением все норм, а с последним нет

Answer (score 0):

Попытался по подсказкам из комментариев реализовать двоичный поиск, получается с этими входными данными:

```py
elements = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
request = [1, 2, 3]
def BinSearchLeft(array, key):
    l = -1
    r = len(array)
    while l < r - 1:
        m = (l + r) // 2
        if array[m] < key:
            l = m
        else: r = m
    return r + 1

def BinSearchRight(array, key):
    l = -1
    r = len(array)
    while l < r - 1:
        m = (l + r) // 2
        if array[m] <= key:
            l = m
        else: r = m
    return r

with open('binsearch.out', 'w') as file:
    for element in request:
        if element in elements:
            print(BinSearchLeft(elements, element),BinSearchRight(elements,element), file=file)
        else: print(-1, -1, file=file)
```

Но почему то выдает ошибку с другими входными данными, где я допустил ошибку?

Comment: Посмотрите мой пример